# Installing Redis on Google Compute Engine and access it from Google App Engine Code

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a specific usecase for Redis on my highly scaled java server on Google App Engine. I want to install redis and eventually create a redis cluster which can be accessed from my GAE server code. Current documentation does not show much information about this. Is there a way we can do this by establishing secure connection between the Redis nodes on GCE and the GAE server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install Redis on your Compute Engine Linux VM and start it. For more info look at Redis Quick Start @  redis.io/topics/quickstart

  ```
  wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
  tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
  cd redis-stable
  make
  ```
- Edit Redis configuration file that can be found at /etc/redis.conf  and secure it for your remote connections [set strong password, change default port (optional) , rename dangerous commands (optional), etc..). Restart redis service after editing config file.

  requirepass foobared

  rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52
- Use redis client libraries (like Jedis) for your Java application on App Engine.

http://redis.io/clients

Comment: Note that you can also completely disable a command by renaming it to the empty string: rename-command CONFIG ""